# Displaying numbers using 7-segment bcd

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, microprocessors

My task is to program PIC16F1517 with bcd 4511 to display numbers counting up from 0 to 9999 using interrupt from TMR0. Counting starts after pressing break button (RB0). Display is connected to PORTD. I used debugger to see how it works but only saw numbers increasing like crazy and not fluently so dont how if its in correct order. Sadly i dont have the thing to see if it works. Could someone check? I'm using MPLAB X IDE v4.01

```
#define LEL PORTC,4
#DEFINE LEH PORTC,5
#DEFINE BI PORTC,2

#include<p16f1517.inc>
    __CONFIG _CONFIG1 ,_FOSC_INTOSC & _WDTE_OFF & _PWRTE_ON & _MCLRE_ON & _CP_OFF & _BOREN_OFF &_CLKOUTEN_OFF
__CONFIG _CONFIG2 , _WRT_OFF & _VCAPEN_OFF & _LVP_OFF
WSKP EQU 0x30;least significant
WSKL EQU 0x31;most significant
ORG 0x00
clrf WSKP
clrf WSKL
goto settings
ORG 0x04

GOTO interupt
 settings
BANKSEL PORTB
CLRF PORTB
CLRF PORTC
CLRF PORTD
BANKSEL ANSELB
CLRF ANSELB
CLRF ANSELC
CLRF ANSELD
BANKSEL LATB
CLRF LATB
CLRF LATC
CLRF LATD
BANKSEL TRISB
MOVLW 0x01
MOVWF TRISB
CLRF TRISC
CLRF TRISD
BANKSEL OPTION_REG
bcf OPTION_REG, 5
bCf OPTION_REG, 3
bsf OPTION_REG, 2
bsf OPTION_REG, 1
bsf OPTION_REG, 0
BANKSEL PORTD
BCF BI
BSF LEL
BCF LEH
bsf PORTC,6
BSF BI

 START
btfsc PORTB,0
goto START
BANKSEL INTCON
BSF INTCON,7;GIE;7
BSF INTCON,5;TMR0IE
goto START

 interupt
bcf PORTC,6
incf WSKP,f
call check
call display
BANKSEL INTCON
bcf INTCON, 2;tmr0if
retfie

 check
MOVFW WSKP
ANDLW 0x0f;check if wskp=10,20,...,90 if so add 0x06 to display correct number
SUBLW 0x0a
BTFSS STATUS,Z
return
MOVLW 0x06
ADDWF WSKP,f
GOTO check1

 check1
movfw WSKP
ANDLW 0xF0;check if wskp=100 if so cleat it and increment wskl
SUBLW 0x60
BTFSS STATUS, Z
RETURN
clrf WSKP
incf WSKL,f
movfw WSKL
andlw 0x0F;check if wskl=10,20,...,90 if so add 0x06 to display correct number
sublw 0x0A
btfss STATUS, Z
RETURN
movlw 0x06
addwf WSKL, f
movfw WSKL
andlw 0xf0;if wskl=100 that means we displayed 9999 then clear to start counting from 0
sublw 0x60
btfss STATUS, Z
RETURN
clrf WSKP
CLRF WSKL
return

 display
bcf BI
bsf LEL
bcf LEH
movfw WSKP
movwf PORTD
bcf LEL
bsf LEL
movfw WSKL
movwf PORTD
bcf LEH
bsf LEH
bsf BI
return
END
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I suggest you to init also `INTCON` register for avoid unpredictable behavior.

After that I think the problem is in the MainLoop and Interrupt code. For MainLoop you set the memory bank for `INTCON` but not for `PORTB`; for interrupt routine you don't set the memory bank at start and don't set the memor bank when you jump in `check`, `check1` and `display` code.
In this way all the variables that you read, write and test must to be in the same memory bank of `INTCON`. Are you sure this is so?